# What "processing" is necessary when releasing documents for a FOIA request?

Tags: united-states, vaccine, freedom-of-information, fda

The story is online:

https://www.reuters.com/legal/government/wait-what-fda-wants-55-years-process-foia-request-over-vaccine-data-2021-11-18/

Overall it looks like the FDA can process 500 pages per month and the FOIA request is for 329,000 pages. The FDA is asking to narrow the request and will not increase the number of pages they process per month.

Now, my question is: what 'processing' is necessary? In the spirit of transparency, shouldn't documents provided by Pfizer be made public AS-IS, without processing?

Since the documents relate to the approval process, which contains data of general interest, wouldn't 'processing' them inherently hide some of the details?

Comment: Did you read the article you linked to beyond the headline? Because it pretty much answers your question.

Comment: Yes I read it; it doesn’t really answer my question: we can assume that the documents are structured so eliminating lists of names or secrets related to manufacturing would be the equivalent of removing sections, not having to do a page per page review. The article is just echoing the FDA’s point of view.

Comment: Who is "we" and on what basis can "we" make assumptions about how these documents are structured?

Comment: “We” as a figure of speech here. Have you ever read medical study documents? They are mostly very organized in clear sections with a logical order. You don’t find things such as patient names scattered across pages, etc. It just doesn’t happen. So, yes, we can expect the documents to be structured and sections can most likely be removed easily. When the docs will be released, if you read them, you’ll probably see very clear areas pertaining to manufacturing, testing, etc

Comment: on page 187392 is the home address of the person who approved the mask design. Do you really want that getting into the hands of the far right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *What 'processing' is necessary?*

Specifically, the redaction of nondisclosable information and, like any editing task, it requires a subject matter expert reading and understanding every page to make certain that nondisclosable information is not revealed.

Note that under § 20.22 (b) there must be an indication of "the amount of information deleted". That can be done by redaction but not by merely removing sections of the document. While a deletion may be indicated by noting that some number of pages have been deleted, it may also require any references to those deleted pages to be redacted.

> **[21 CFR § 20.20](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/21/20.20) Policy on disclosure of Food and Drug Administration records.**
>
> (a) The Food and Drug Administration will make the fullest possible disclosure of records to the public, consistent with the rights of individuals to privacy, the property rights of persons in trade secrets and confidential commercial or financial information, and the need for the agency to promote frank internal policy deliberations and to pursue its regulatory activities without disruption.

> **[21 CFR § 20.22](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/21/20.22) Partial disclosure of records.**
>
> (a) If a record contains both disclosable and nondisclosable information, the nondisclosable information will be deleted and the remaining record will be disclosed unless the two are so inextricably intertwined that it is not feasible to separate them or release of the disclosable information would compromise or impinge upon the nondisclosable portion of the record.
>
> (b)
>
> > (1) Whenever information is deleted from a record that contains both disclosable and nondisclosable information, the amount of information deleted shall be indicated on the portion of the record that is made available, unless including that indication would harm an interest protected by an exemption under the Freedom of Information Act.
> >
> > (2) When technically feasible, the amount of information deleted shall be indicated at the place in the record where the deletion is made.

---

Q: *In the spirit of transparency, shouldn't documents provided by Pfizer be made public AS-IS, without processing?*

No, an individual's privacy and company trade secret rights outweigh the public's right to know.

---

Q: *Since the documents relate to the approval process, which contains data of general interest, wouldn't 'processing' them inherently hide some of the details?*

Yes, but the public need not know the names of those who suffered adverse reactions to a drug, though the adverse reaction must be disclosed. Nor does the public need to know trade secrets, though competitors would.

Answer (score 4):

Several principles are interacting here:

- The public has an interest in transparency of government processes and documentation. This is generally considered legitimate, with the usual broad exceptions of individual privacy, national security, and so on.
- A company has an interest to keep internal documents secret to protect their 'intellectual property' and competitive advantage. This is generally considered legitimate, again with broad exceptions like whistle-blowing on misconduct, and so on.
- The government has an interest to see company documents as part of their drug approval process. This is generally considered legitimate, even for documents that the company would otherwise wish to protect.

One could argue that in a case like COVID vaccines, the public interest to know takes precedence over the company's interest to keep their data secret. But what if the data also contains PII (personally identifying information) of individuals? What if with the next vaccine application, companies argue that they have a need to withold details from the FDA because it *could* become public later on?

Now, the inability of the FDA to process more than 500 pages a month would be a bad joke, or perhaps intentional obstruction, if that was the **only** information request they have to process. Even so, they should be able to give higher priority to something as important as COVID. But what about all the other legitimate requests that would take a back seat?

The FDA could also argue that they need funding for a dozen lawyers and clerks to do this more quickly, but again, what about all the other requests?